# JQuery Append To Dynamically Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically appending a `div` element to an existing `div`.  But immediately following that, I need to append another `div` to the `div` I just created dynamically.  But I can't seem to find the dynamically created `div` in order to append to it.  I assume maybe the DOM isn't aware of that `div` yet since I just made it.  How do I do this?

```
var serialModel = "Test Test";
$("#existingDiv").append("<div id = '" + serialModel + "'></div>");
$("#" + serialModel).append("<div>content here</div>")
```

The last line doesn't do anything.  The second line produces the new div, but then I can't find it to append to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if you do it vice versa:

```
$("<div />", { id : serialModel })     // create `<div>` with `serialModel` as ID
    .append("<div>content here</div>") // append new `<div>` to it
    .appendTo("#existingDiv");         // append all to `#existingDiv`
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but the serialModel div is never created.

Comment: You're totally right.  I had a slight typo in mine.  I'm off and running now.  Thanks!